# Direct access to pictureBox.Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I'm very frequently modifying an image within the picturebox so I though I would do something like this:

```
modify(ref pictureBox1.Image);
```

unfortunately it doesn't work, it throws a following error "A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter". Ok, I get the error - but still is there any work around or something to speed up my program?

Comment: Read more on parameter passing here it's already a reference type: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects (reference types) in .NET are passed by reference, there is no benefit in adding ref keyword. Try this:

```
var image = pictureBox.Image;
modify(image);
```

Comment: oops... ur right - I just didn't realize this difference between c++ and c#. thanks.